# Append anchor tag

Tags: jquery, html

In my application, I want to make an image a link to another page. Image is placed in html as,

```
<div class="rightbuttoncontainers_footer">
  <div class="forfooterimg" id="twitterlink_indv">
    <img src="Images/tweatus.png" width="30" height="30" alt="tweat">
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to make those image as links via script, I tried the following

```
var twit_lk='https://twitter.com/';
$('#twitterlink_indv').append('<a href="'+twit_lk+'"/>');
```

But the output of the above code is like this,

```
<div class="rightbuttoncontainers_footer">
  <div class="forfooterimg" id="twitterlink_indv">
    <img src="Images/tweatus.png" width="30" height="30" alt="tweat">
    <a href="https://twitter.com/"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

But, I want the output like the following,

```
<div class="rightbuttoncontainers_footer">
  <div class="forfooterimg" id="twitterlink_indv">
    <a href="https://twitter.com/">
      <img src="Images/tweatus.png" width="30" height="30" alt="tweat">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I make it work?

Please help,

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at `.wrap()` method documented [here](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/).

```
$('#twitterlink_indv img').wrap('<a href="' + twit_lk + '" />');
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`wrap` method](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/). Select the image element and wrap the link around it:

```
$('#twitterlink_indv img').wrap('<a href="'+twit_lk+'"></a>');
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [**.wrap()**](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) , like this:

```
$('#twitterlink_indv img').wrap('<a href="'+twit_lk+'"/>');
```

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
$('#twitterlink_indv img').wrap(
    $("<a/>").attr("href", twit_lk));
```

Answer (score 1):

try using [`wrap`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) instead of [`append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) like this:

```
$('#twitterlink_indv img').wrap('<a href="'+twit_lk+'"/>');
```

Answer (score 1):

What I think you are looking for is the jQuery `wrap()` function.

> Wrap an HTML structure around each element in the set of matched elements.

```
$('#twitterlink_indv > img').wrap('<a href="' + twit_lk + '" />');
```

Your selector should be altered to match the inner `<img>` tag. The wrap function will then wrap the matched elements with an anchor tag.

#### Take a look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/NqNVB/) for a demo.

> References -
>
> - [`wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/)

Answer (score 0):

use jquery `wrap()`:

```
$('#twitterlink_indv > img').wrap('<a href="'+twit_lk+'"/>');
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use the `wrapInner()` method:

```
$('#twitterlink_indv').wrapInner('<a href="'+twit_lk+'"/>');
```